# Two NSTableView on one View

Tags: objective-c, macos

I want to have the form (view) with two NSTableView.  One NSTableView will display the category of the inventory items.  When user select the item category I want to display the inventory items in the second NSTableView.

I have NSMutableDictionary where the keys are the inventory item groups.  The values of the dictionary is a NSMutableArray with the Item objects:

```
@implementation sfAppDelegate {
   NSMutableDictionary *allTheData;
}
```

To work with NSTableView I need to realize methods:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tv {
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
-(void)tableViewSelectionIsChanging:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
```

As I have two NSTableViews on the View I can not implement this method twice in the one class AppDelegate.  So I implement this methods in the AppDelegate for the first NSTableView (with Items groups) and create new class ItemList for the second NSTableView.  I have used Cmd+Drag'n'Drop to set this class as datasource and delegate for second NSTableView.

But I don't create the instance of ItemList class. It is created automatically as I see and I don't know where and how.  But I need to have the pointer to this instance to pass the selected Item Category to it.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just put an branch inside your delegate methods like this:

```
-(id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tv objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
if(tv==firstTableView) {
   //Do stuff related to the first table view
else if (tv==secondTableView) {
   //Do stuff ralated to the second table view
}
```

That way you don't have to use separate classes to handle the two tableviews, and you will have all the references you need in the same file.

Comment: Thanks.  It can be a solution. But I want to find more general solution. The Xcode (or Framework) automatically creates instances of all visual elements which I am using.  And it automatically create all instances of all classes for which I have created Outlets.  I wnat to know, how can I pass parameters to this instances.

Answer (score 1):

To have two independent table views you would need a Root Controller which contains two child table controllers. Both child controllers will delegate back table selections to root controller.

So when some one clicks on FirstTable, RootController will notify SecondTable and pass relevant data. That way you can have two classes implementing the tableView delegates and datasources methods.

Comment: Thanks.  I have been working with XCode only one week.  Can you please recommend me some tutorial about Root Controller ?